# correlation statistics

Tags: self-study

I want to do a proposed study on the frequency of a sleep disorder, namely sleep paralysis,and test to see if a trait for mindfulness is correlated with it. A questionnaire will be given to people that may have this disorder to confirm that they do and a scale to measure mindfulness will also be given. So the scale measures for mindfulness are on a 6 point Likert scale so that would be an interval scale I suppose. I guess after I receive the results from the sleep paralysis survey I can categorize the frequencies of the experience accordingly to show the correlation..? So the idea is to simply test the alternate hypothesis that people who experience sleep paralysis more frequently have less trait for mindfulness...So I know this is correlational by design but exactly what statistics to use I am not sure of....

Comment: what test would you use in order to reject or accept a null hypothesis?

Comment: @PyCthon... would I need to consider the null if it is correlational...I assumed that would apply when you want to say that one variable causes another.. I am not sure

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have a 6 point scale, it's not interval. If the scale is the sum of many 6 point scales, then possibly it can be treated as interval, although it technically is not.

Then if you just want a correlation, you should probably use Spearman rank rather than Pearson; but you may want some form of regression if you have a dependent and an independent variable. If the dependent variable is 1 to 6, then ordinal regression might be a good place to start.

Comment: @ Peter Flom....ok the questionnaire consists of 15 items and each is answered according to the 6 point scale.... would that qualify as interval?

Comment: also in respect to same question to inquire about the frequency of sleep paralysis there is also a questionnaire to test for the sleep disorder which contains 17 questions the majority are 4 point likert scale and some are open ended, however, the frequency of the event is what I would be interested in as far as referencing correlation...the remaining questions would qualify one as having the experience for the most part...

Comment: If the questions lend themselves to it, you might consider redefining the scale anchor points so the scale is interval (e.g., number of hours, number of days, rather than often, sometimes, rarely).

Comment: If you are really interested in frequency of the event, then just do your analyses on that.  Those data would seem to be interval.